# meta_where code not being recognized

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I used meta_where on a rails project last summer and it worked.  However trying to set up a rails project at a distance using the screen sharing site "join.me" I'm getting errors when the code gets to the first line that uses meta_where ("matches").
     I've put "gem 'meta_where'" in the Gemfile and "bundle install" gives the error:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
     In Gemfile:

```
        meta_where depends on
```

activerecord(~>3.0.0.rc2)

activerecord (3.1.0)

and yet when I use the gem server and check the installed gems on the webpage there are 2 versions of activerecord (3.0.9 and 3.1.0) and meta_where-1.0.4 is listed.
     It seems that the code is looking in the wrong directory, but that's just a wild guess.  What's the problem?
       Thanks,
              Barney

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, `meta_where` depends on Rails 3.0 (NOT 3.1). are you using rvm? you should create a rails 3.0 project, if you need `meta_where`. if you're using rvm, you can simply create another gemset, and

```
rvm gemset create rails30
rvm gemset use rails30
gem install bundler
gem install rails -v=3.0.10
```

then create a Rails 3.0 project

```
rails new my_project
```

and so on

Comment: Hi Marian,  the sysadmin set up the ruby and rails environment for me and the plan was to copy over my code.  I didn't think to look for differences in Rails versions.  1) Does he have to delete Rails and reload an older version of it?  2) I don't know rvm.  I'll look it up.

Comment: if this is a production machine with no other rails app running, probably the easiest way would be to remove all versions of the rails gem and install rails 3.0.10, but nevertheless, rvm is worth looking into!

Comment: Thank you, Marian, I'll look into doing both of those things on Monday.      Barney